# Destructuring Objects and default parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring

I have a problem to solve involving default parameters and object destructuring.
I have an object 'product' with this shape:

```
{
     name: "Slip Dress",
     priceInCents: 8800,
     availableSizes: [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16 ]
   }
```

Here is my code so far, but I am receiving an error that 'availableSizes' is not iterable. Can someone help me correct this code?

I have tried adjusting the default parameters in my function and I have moved my return statements to no avail.

```
function checkIfSizeIsAvailable(product = {availableSizes:[]}, size = 0) {
  // let availableSizes = product;
  let foundSize = "";
  for (let sizeCheck of product.availableSizes) {
    if (sizeCheck === size) {
      foundSize = size;
    }
  }
  if (foundSize === ""){
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  //for (let i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
  // return false;
}
```

Comment: There is no destructuring in your code. You just have a default parameter. Presumably you pass an actual value for `product` which doesn't have `availableSizes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As VLAZ mentioned in a comment, you can pass an object without an `availableSizes` field and it'll cause that error.

Destructuring happens when your variables together form an object/array on the left-hand size of the assignment:

```js
function checkIfSizeIsAvailable(product = {availableSizes:[]}, size = 0) {
  // ^ Because of the default parameter, product always exists
  // Now we actually destructure with a default value for missing fields
  const { availableSizes = [] } = product;
}
```

or more compact:

```js
function checkIfSizeIsAvailable({ availableSizes = [] } = {availableSizes:[]}, size = 0) {

}
```

Mind that this does not defend against non-array values, or even falsy values. A user can pass `{ availableSizes: false }` and your `availableSizes` would also be `false`.

Comment: Or even more compact: `function checkIfSizeIsAvailable({ availableSizes = [] } = {}, size = 0)`

Comment: Also, the body of the function can be compacted to `return availableSizes.includes(size)`

Comment: That worked! Thanks for helping me solve this one.